# Unable to register route with express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have upgrade my application to babel 6.
In my server.js I'm trying to setup all routes

```
require("./routes")(app);

app.listen(config.port, () => {
      console.log('Server started: http://localhost:' + config.port);
});
```

In my routes.js file

```
export default function (app) {
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index.html");
  });
}
```

While i'm trying to run application gives an error

> TypeError: require(...) is not a function

I have define presets es2015 in **.babelrc**, Cant find out whats wrong in this earlier with former babel it was working fine.
Guys please any one have idea.

Comment: Side note: You may consider using [`Router`s](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router). With them, you can remove the need for passing the `app` around – `app.use(require('./routes'));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Babel converts the module to ES5, it assigns the default export to the `exports.default`.

```
exports.default = function (app) {
  app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("index.html");
  });
};
```

To use it without `import`, you'll have to reference the property:

```
require("./routes").default(app);
```

---

The `.default` property is used by it to avoid modifying the `default` export when additional `export`s are given along with it, since they all have to be provided through `module.exports`.

Comment: Thank you **Jonathan** ! Its done I just need to add `require("./routes").default(app);`